# Mysql data type for LZ-string compressed text

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Which type of `mysql` data for `LZ-string` compresses results? 
Variable for this, in my database is `MEDIUMTEXT` type and collation `UTF8bin`. After compress and send to the database with the post method(`asp.net core web services`), it was not written correctly in the database.

Send data to `mysql` database(post method) is: `㊁炆ౠ혏恮԰ᎀ찃挃뤀` 
Written data in database is: `??????????`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved. Problem it wasn't in mysql.
Problem it was in web services, in connection string.

```
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=webshopmobiletown;user=root;password=;");
```

to

```
optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=webshopmobiletown;user=root;password=;CharSet=utf8;");
```